# Is there a way to do a second-level domain search in linux?

Tags: whois

When using `whois` in linux, I notice that it fails to return results for second-level domain search like `ubuy.com.se`.

Output:

```
 domain "ubuy.com.se" not found.
```

Is there any alternative I can use in linux for this type of search?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer at this Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64867874/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-second-level-domain-search-in-linux, which has since been deleted.

`whois -h whois.centralnic.com domainexample.com.se`

Comment: The question used the example of "ubuy.com.se"; would you want to use that same example in your answer, for consistency?